# Prove integral inequality of $C^1$ function

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f$ be $C^1$ class over $[a,b]$. Asuume that $f(a)=f(b)=0$ prove that: $\displaystyle \sup_{t\in [a,b]} |f(t)| \le \frac{1}{2}\int_a^b |f'(t)| dt$

I tried to show it from C-S ineq. for integrals and I came to form:

$\displaystyle \sup_{t\in [a,b]} |f(t)| \le \frac{1}{2}\sqrt{(b-a)\int_a^b (f'(t))^2 dt}$

and stuck

Comment: By continuity, the supremum is attained, say at $\xi \in (a,b)$. Can you see a relation between $f(\xi)$ and integrals of $f'$?

Comment: can you give hint to this relation?

Comment: Look at Michael Burr's answer.

Comment: @DanielFischer why sup is attained at $(a,b)$ if we consider $(x-1)(x+1)$ and $a=-1 b=1$ then it's not true

Comment: I'm referring to $\sup \{ \lvert f(x)\rvert : x \in [a,b]\}$. That can correspond to the supremum (maximum, by continuity and compactness) or the infimum (minimum) of $\{ f(t) : t \in [a,b]\}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\sup_{t\in\left[a,b\right]}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|=\left|f\left(c\right)\right|,c\in\left[a,b\right].
 $ We have $$ 2\sup_{t\in\left[a,b\right]}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|=\left|2f\left(c\right)\right|=\left|\int_{a}^{c}f'\left(s\right)ds-\int_{c}^{b}f'\left(s\right)ds\right|\leq \int_{a}^{c}\left|f'\left(s\right)\right|ds+\int_{c}^{b}\left|f'\left(s\right)\right|ds=\int_{a}^{b}\left|f'\left(s\right)\right|ds.
 $$

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose first that the function is always positive, increases monotonically until it reaches a maximum at $x=c$ where $c\in(a,b)$ and then decreases monotonically.  In this case:

$$
\int_a^b|f'(t)|dt=\int_a^cf'(t)dt-\int_c^bf'(t)dt.
$$

Using the FTC, we know that this becomes

$$
[f(c)-f(a)]-[f(b)-f(c)]=2f(c).
$$

Therefore, in this case, 
$$
\sup_{x\in[a,b]} |f(x)|=\frac{1}{2}
\int_a^b|f'(t)|dt.
$$

Now, generalize.

Comment: my idea is to divide interval $[a,b]$ over monotonical $[a,x_1], [x_1,x_2],…,[x_n, b]$ and they alternate (meaning starts from increasing then decreasing and so on or starts decreasing) but then we have something like $\displaystyle \int_a^b |f'(t)|dt=2f(x_1)-2f(x_2)+…+2f(x_c)+…+2f(x_n)$. Is it good way ?

Comment: This is a reasonable approach, I suggest characterizing the sign of the coefficients.  Personally, I would divide the interval at the zeros and use the extreme value theorem.

Comment: zeros of f or f' ?

Comment: Zeros of $f$, but do try your way first.